# Ruby - SQLite3 - set pragmas from code

Tags: ruby, sqlite

I am using `Ruby SQLite3` (1.13.11) on macos (Ruby 2.0.0-p247) to create a few databases for my application. I need to set some pragmas, but I am not sure I am doing the right thing. This is what I do to set `PRAGMA synchronous = OFF`

```
db = SQLite3::Database.new("test.db")
db.synchronous
2
db.synchronous = 0
db.synchronous
0
```

This seems to work, but when I open my `test.db` with `DB Browser for SQLite`, `synchronous` is still set to `Full`.

I also tried

```
db.execute("PRAGMA synchronous = OFF")
```

with the same result.

Is `synchronous` associated with the connection? Is this the case for all `PRAGMAS`?

Answer (score 0):

Some PRAGMAs are associated with the current database connection so they are not persisted between sessions. For example: [journal_mode](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_journal_mode)

For a list of all PRAGMAS refer to [this](https://sqlite.org/pragma.html) link